# SQL query to measure historic response times to requests

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table containing a series of requests for information, let's call it `requests`:

```
| key | Individual | Date       | Due date   |
| 0   | 1          | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-10 |
| 1   | 2          | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-11 |
| 2   | 2          | 2019-01-03 | 2019-01-11 |
```

Each of these request rows causes a user to be notified of the requirement to complete the task (what the task is doesn't matter). When they complete the task, a row is entered into another table, call it `completions`.

```
| key | Individual | Date       |
| 10  |        1   | 2018-12-28 |
| 11  |        2   | 2019-01-05 |
| 12  |        2   | 2019-01-06 |
```

A request is deemed to be fulfilled if a completion occurs for the task (by the individual) with a date *greater* than the date the request was made. A single completion will resolve all outstanding requests for that user as long as the requests have a date less than that of the completion (ie the request came in before the task was completed).

Ultimately what I want is to create a view that logs the time it took for each request to be fulfilled, both in terms of the number of days since the request was made, as well has how many days to the due date (or how many days overdue).

In order to achieve this I think I need an intermediate view that tells me which completion fulfills each request (if there are any)

So I want a query that generates the following:

```
| RequestKey | CompletedBy |
| 0          | NULL        |
| 1          | 11          |
| 2          | 11          |
```

Request 0 was never filled since completion 10 happened before the request was made. Request 1 and 2 we're both filled by completion 11 since it was the first completion to occur after each of those requests were made.

Going from here to a final view that tells me the amount of time it took to fill the the request, time overdue, etc. Is easy because I can just do a join on the tables and count the difference between the completion date and request date, but it's not quite clear to me how I can get to the above table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the completion date for each request using `outer apply`:

```
select r.*, c.date as completion_date,
       datediff(day, r.date, c.date) as days_to_completion
from requests r outer apply
     (select top (1) c.*
      from completions c
      where c.individual = r.individual and
            c.date >= r.date
      order by c.date desc
     ) c;
```